# Select first item in each list

Tags: python, list, loops, select, iteration

Here is my list:

```
[(('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D')), (('E', 'F'), ('G', 'H'))]
```

Basically, I'd like to get:

```
[('A', 'C'), ('E', 'G')]
```

So, I'd like to select first elements from the lowest-level lists and build mid-level lists with them.

====================================================

Additional explanation below:

I could just zip them by

```
list(zip([w[0][0] for w in list1], [w[1][0] for w in list1]))
```

But later I'd like to add a condition: the second elements in the lowest level lists must be `'B'` and `'D'` respectively, so the final outcome should be:

```
[('A', 'C')] # ('E', 'G') must be sorted out
```

I'm a beginner, but can't find the case anywhere... Would be grateful for help.

Comment: Could you please share your attempt at solving this, so we know exactly what we can help you with?

Comment: @yatu Thanks, I added the explanation. Basically, I tried zipping (which worked), but, later, I'll need to filter out some lists by condition. And, if so, zipping will not help. Well, simple looping `[x[0] for x in some_list]` is not working here. If it'd be possible to do something like `x[][][0]` - but it does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it the following way

```
list = [(('A', 'B'), ('C', 'D')), (('E', 'F'), ('G', 'H'))]  
out = [] 
for i in list:
   listAux = []
   for j in i:
       listAux.append(j[0])
   out.append((listAux[0],listAux[1]))  
print(out)
```

I hope that's what you're looking for.